# Problem with Simple HTML DOM Error Handling

Tags: simple-html-dom

I have list of website which I am passing to function doScrape() this function creates SimpleHtmlDom object and load the url passed to it as a argument.

But when **scraper** is in progress one url can't be loaded and PHP throws following exception

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.somesite.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in F:\xampp\htdocs\scraping\scraper\simple_html_dom.php on line 850

Due to this error entire **scraper** stops working. How to handle this exception and keep **scraper** running event there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$data = @file_get_contents(http://www.somesite.com);
if($data){
    //Ok
}else{
    //Error
}
```